# Can't control img direction (rtl ltf)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem getting my images to show rtl. I want to show as normal but I can't find the code to change

I  need code to force all img to look normal using JavaScript or CSS?

```css
  
 .carousel-inner .item > img {
 transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
 filter: FlipV;
    -ms-filter: "FlipV";
}
```

When I delete that code ... nothing happens!
There's a problem in class `.item` and I can't remove that class because a lot of things go wrong in the website.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation doesn't flip, you want:

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
-ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

Comment: same problem  img slider LTR  don't know why !

Comment: What do you mean, what exactly is the issue? Can you put it on JS fiddle?